# Cannot write @ on the Danish Mac Keybord layout

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, macbook

I have installed Loki on my MacBook Pro mid 2012.

The Danish keyboard layout for Mac doesn't work for me, as I cannot use <kbd>@</kbd>.

The Danish keybord has an option to write <kbd>@</kbd>, but it doesn't seem to work.... Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem. The alternative/option key does not seam to work.

Comment: Under 'Danish' language there are no less than [6 different layouts](https://postimg.org/image/z0utar3bl/): have you tested others?